# How to add partition for UBUNTU 12.04 in my MacBook Pro 7.1 that already have Windows XP and OS X 10.6.8 (bootcamp)?

Tags: installation, partitioning, disk, macbook-pro, bootcamp

I have Windows XP and OSX 10.6.8 in my mac via bootcamp. Now that I want to install Ubuntu, I want to add 2 extra partitions (for LINUX and LINUX swap). Previously only Macintosh HD and BOOTCAMP for Windows XP.

However, the partition can't be made. The message says that the verification failed.

Can anyone help me to partition my hard drive?

FYI: I am using DiskUtility.

Answer (score -2):

on diskutility do the partition leaving the partition as "free space" then from ubuntu intaller configure it, here is a guide but is in spanish... is for kubuntu, but I guess should be similar 
http://blueleaflinux.blogspot.com/2012/04/guia-de-instalacion-de-kubuntu-1204_25.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.